# get_body from IHTMLDocument2 crash program

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

program crash

> First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MFCApplication4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

```
    HINSTANCE hInst = ::LoadLibrary(_T("OLEACC.DLL"));
    CoInitialize(NULL);


    if (hInst != NULL)
    {
        if (parentWindow != NULL)
        {


            if (childWindow)
            {
                CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spDoc;
                LRESULT lRes;

                UINT nMsg = ::RegisterWindowMessage(_T("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT"));
                ::SendMessageTimeout(childWindow, nMsg, 0L, 0L, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, (DWORD*)&lRes);

                LPFNOBJECTFROMLRESULT pfObjectFromLresult = (LPFNOBJECTFROMLRESULT)::GetProcAddress(hInst, LPCSTR("ObjectFromLresult"));
                if (pfObjectFromLresult != NULL)
                {
                    HRESULT hr;
                    hr = (*pfObjectFromLresult)(lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument, 0, (void**)&spDoc);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        CComPtr<IHTMLElement> pHTMLElement;
                        hr = spDoc->get_body(&pHTMLElement);// <-this line breaks the program 
                        //BSTR bstrText;
                        //pHTMLElement->get_innerText(&bstrText);

                        //edit1->SetWindowTextW(bstrText);

                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        ::FreeLibrary(hInst);
    } 
    CoUninitialize();
```

i'm executing this code from a button from MFC dialog app just to test the code
this is the autos

- &pHTMLElement   0x00ddeb10 0x00000000 
  ATL::CComPtr *
- hr  S_OK        HRESULT
- pHTMLElement    0x00000000    ATL::CComPtr
- spDoc   0x03303f7c {...}    ATL::CComPtr
- this    0x00ddfbd8 {hWnd=0x001905b6 {unused=??? }}  CMFCApplication4Dlg *

i don't know what is the mistake

Comment: The word is crash not crush, FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
hr = (*pfObjectFromLresult)(lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument, 0, (void**)&spDoc);
```

You are requesting an `IHTMLDocument`, but you are giving it a pointer to a `IHTMLDocument2`.

Comment: thank you i copied the code from this post https://huitey.wordpress.com/2009/09/11/how-to-get-ihtmldocument2-from-a-hwnd/

Comment: @nizzard0094 obviously, that post is wrong for the same reason (which I have now commented on). When you request an interface via an IID, you must provide a pointer to the same interface type that you are requesting.